# How to minus current and previous value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have one table, need to minus one column previous and current amount. Table value is below, need to write syntax for `Cal-Amount` column

```
Id Amount Cal-Amount
 1  100   0
 2  200   0
 3  400   0
 4  500   0
```

`Cal-Amount` calculation formula with sample value

```
Id Amount Cal-Amount
 1  100   (0-100)=100
 2  200   (100-200)=100
 3  400   (200-400)=200
 4  500   (400-500)=100
```

Need SQL syntax to minus column current and previous value

Comment: What sql server version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LAG` is one option if you are using SQL Server 2012 or later:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Amount,
    LAG(Amount, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Id) - Amount AS [Cal-Amount]
FROM yourTable;
```

If you are using an earlier version of SQL Server, then we can use a self join:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Amount,
    COALESCE(t2.Amount, 0) - t1.Amount AS [Cal-Amount]
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.Id = t2.Id + 1;
```

But note that the self join option might only work if the `Id` values are continuous.  LAG is probably the most efficient way to do this, and is also robust to non sequential `Id` values, so long as the order is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Tim beat me to the lag(), so here's the old-school using join:

```
select t.Id,t.Amount,t.Amount-isnull(t2.Amount,0) AS [Cal-Amount]
from yourtable t
left join yourtable t2 on t.id=t2.id+1
```

Comment: Don't forget about the first record. You'll need a left join and either a coalesce or a insull to hand the first row of data set.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2012 or newer:

```
Select 
    ID, Amount, [Cal-Amount] = Amount - LAG(Amount, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Id)
From 
    table
```

or

```
Select 
    current.ID, Current.Amount, Current.Amount - Isnull(Prior.Amount, 0)
from 
    table current 
left join 
    table prior on current.id - 1 = prior.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LAG function if your SQL Server >= 2012

```
declare @t table (id int, amount1 int)

insert into @t
values (1, 100), (2, 200), (3, 400), (4, 500)

select
    *, amount1 - LAG(amount1, 1, 0) over (order by id) as CalAmount 
from 
    @t
```

Comment: Oh well Tim was faster then me, so his answer should of cause be accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `apply` :

```
select t.*, t.Amount - coalesce(tt.Amount, 0) as CalAmount
from table t outer apply (
     select top (1) *
     from table t1
     where t1.id < t.id
     order by t1.id desc
) tt;
```